# Instead of taking an ordinal number [2nd] in voice recognition it is taking [second] as an audio input

Tags: bots, amazon-lex

In the Postal Address slot-type I want a user to speak output as a following way - "190 east 72nd street"

But it takes input as "190 east 70 second street"
which is not appropriate.

So is there any way? I have tried doing with SSML tags but not getting proper output. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest adding your own parsing logic to catch these. Lex Settings will not provide you with enough control to do it, and SSML tags are only for Lex's outgoing responses.

Comment: Thank you @JayA.Little Yes I had to build my own parsing logic.

Comment: If you are feeling generous, you could include the parsing code you wrote in an answer to this question and mark it as correct. That's encouraged here if you fixed your own problem, and helps others who have the same question and come here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use a regular expression and we can replace the string with the correct output.

`import re
if "0 second" in postal:
    y = re.sub("0 second","2nd",postal)
elif "second" in postal:
    y = re.sub("second","2nd", postal)
else:
    y = postal`